# I am unable to compile a program which has assembly language instructions

Tags: c

I compiled a C program (which has some assembly language instructions) like this.

```
TCC -Emasm.exe protect.c
```

It gives an error `Unable to execute masm.exe`.
What should I do or where can I find `masm.exe`?

Comment: Are you from the past?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12654 or ml.exe

Comment: What happens when you don't specify `-Emasm.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get microsoft assembly compiler, which is called masm.